# Can someone point me to a good resource for Ubuntu Studio, Jac, Ardour, LMMS, QTractor, etc?

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I moved from Mac to Linux, and one of the things I loved on my mac was starting Garageband, having my Keystation Pro 88 plugged in via USB, and just starting to play with some great sounds.

I'm really not getting that experience (at all) so far on Ubuntu Studio.  I understand there's some learning on how to setup Jack, and make things connect, and maybe even getting a sound out...but seriously.  Why is this so complicated?

I just want to start an application, pick a track with a piano on it, move to my Keystation, and start playing.  I'd really like to know that shortest distance to there from scratch.

I'm not sure what these video tutorials are talking about, but surely there's a tutorial out there for the "So, you've never done this at all before, and have no clue where to start" person like.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

There are no good video tutorials that i know of yet for setting up JACK using the new Ubuntu Studio Controls settings
Previous ways of starting JACK using qjackctl or similar are a bit more complex
and may confuse more than help

Ubuntu studio has an [Audio Handbook](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/AudioHandbook) guide to most of the basics of using JACK and relevant packages
There is also the [AV Linux manual](http://bandshed.net/pdf/AVL2019UserManual.pdf) but it is a slightly different distribution to Ubuntu Studio using different packages, but may have some useful general information

There is only one additional step required in your suggested workflow, which is to have JACK audio server running before loading any packages that need it

working out the JACK settings in Ubuntu Studio Controls is the first and least trivial part. once you have everything running it can be set to run from when system is booted, or started and stopped when needed

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I'lm slowly getting more adept at getting everything running.